# Performing a uniform crossover of parents

Tags: sampling, uniform-distribution, genetic-algorithms

I'm trying to do a crossover of two vectors in my program. There are two vectors, each a parent in a sense, and they're both a series of random binary digits (1's and 0's). My goal is to randomly sample from both vectors to create a new 'child' which is of the same length as one of the 'parents.' However, when I tried to use this code:

```
sample(c(father,mother), length(father), replace = TRUE)
```

It seems to sample from the entire vector at once for each position in this new child vector. Therefore I'm not getting the uniform crossover that I'm looking for. Before I wanted it to sample randomly from the first index of either the father or the mother. Then for the second index, again sample randomly from either the father or the mother's second index, etc.. Does anyone know how to fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from wrtsvkfm describes single-point crossover, which is viable but not what you've asked about.  (Also, two-point crossover is usually better than single point - I think there's a comparison paper it there that shows this.)

In your code, you've concatenated the mother and father genes and are just sampling randomly from the concatenation of 0s and 1s.  This approach will not preserve any useful characteristic of the genomes that has evolved and will only preserve the relative proportions of zeros and ones, albeit in a random order.

For uniform crossover, what you need to do is sample the possible bit positions at whatever crossover rate you need, and then swap those between parents.  Something like:

```
l = length(father)
i = sample(1:l, floor(l*rate), replace= FALSE)
child1 = mother
child1[i] = father[i]
child2 = father
child 2[i] = mother[i]
```

rate is your cross-over rate, and I assume father and mother genomes are the same length.  (I'm typing this on a mobile phone, so I haven't tested this.)

Answer (score 1):

For genetic algorithms, you simply need to determine the gene within both parental chromosomes (bit vectors) where you will swap the tail ends of both parents chromosomes.

For example, if there are 10 genes in each chromosome, and you have two parents,

0101001010

1110010100

and the random position to swap the tails is at gene 4, then just cut at 4:

0101  001010

1110  010100

and swap the tails:

0101  010100

1110  001010

resulting in two new chidren:

0101010100

1110001010

Look's like R programming code.  Probably look up a swap vector command.
For your own edification, just find out how to draw a random integer in the range 1 to #genes, and then set the one tail to a buffer array, copy the mothers tail to the father's chromosome, and then copy the buffer to the mother's tail.

Also, don't forget mutation and knowing which method for selecting parents for mating is best.